# Laravel 9 - on the fly custom request triggers validation immediately

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I need to create a Laravel custom request on the fly. But when i do, the validation get triggered immediately. I have no idea why.This is my code:

```
// this is in my ProjectController class. When a project gets created, i want the customer contact to be saved with it.

public function store(StoreProjectRequest $request)
{
    //dd($request->only('contact')['contact']);
    $storeContactReq = app()->make(\App\Http\Requests\StoreContactRequest::class);
    //the validation gets triggered right here, before i have the chance to add my request data
    // even if i dd() here, i dont even reach this line of code
    $storeContactReq->request->add($request->only('contact')['contact']); //yes this is correct
    $storeContactReq->setMethod('POST');
       
    $cc = new ContactController();
    $con = $cc->store($storeContactReq);
    dd($con);
    //....
}
```

Here's my StoreContactRequest:

```
class StoreContactRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        //later
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            "lastname" => 'required',
            "firstname" => 'required',
            "email" => 'required|email',
            "phone" => 'required',
            "street" => 'required',
            "house" => 'required',
            "postcode" => 'required',
            "city" => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'firstname.required' => 'Vorname ist leer',
            'lastname.required' => 'Nachname ist leer',
            'street.required' => 'Straße ist leer',
            'house.required' => 'Hausnummer ist leer',
            'postcode.required' => 'Postleitzahl ist leer',
            'city.required' => 'Ort ist leer',
            'phone.required' => 'Telefon ist leer',
            'email.required' => 'Email ist leer',
            'email.email' => 'Email ist keine korrekte Mailadresse'
        ];
    }

    public function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        dd($validator->errors());
    }
```

The error message:

```
Illuminate\Support\MessageBag^ {#1359 // app/Http/Requests/StoreContactRequest.php:56
  #messages: array:8 [
    "lastname" => array:1 [
      0 => "Nachname ist leer"
    ]
    "firstname" => array:1 [
      0 => "Vorname ist leer"
    ]
    "email" => array:1 [
      0 => "Email ist leer"
    ]
    "phone" => array:1 [
      0 => "Telefon ist leer"
    ]
    "street" => array:1 [
      0 => "Straße ist leer"
    ]
    "house" => array:1 [
      0 => "Hausnummer ist leer"
    ]
    "postcode" => array:1 [
      0 => "Postleitzahl ist leer"
    ]
    "city" => array:1 [
      0 => "Ort ist leer"
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

I googled a lot and looked into the documentation, but i just cant find anything about this problem...

I expect the validation to be triggered inside the ContactController::store() function, not when i manually create the StoreContactRequest and before i can add any data to it....

thx

Comment: those are Form Requests, they are validated when resolved .. since you are resolving an instance from the container (`app()->make(...)`) then it will be validated immediately (that is how they work) .... why do you need an instance of this particular request class?

Comment: @lagbox I want to validate the input. I have a Command, which checks incoming emails every minute. The emails contain customer data and some other stuff. From these Data i want to create a new Project. The Project has a constrained table Contacts. The Problem is the same for Projects and Contacts I need to validate all this. I cant Http::post(...), because then i get a 419 session expired (because there is no session for a Command). I also cant $req = new StoreProjectRequest() because then its created without validator at all.

Comment: Context: that app is for a company which receives contactdata of potential customers from several onlineservices. Competitors receive these contactdata also, and my app shall enable my company to be always the first who answers automatically. Therefore i have to create everything from within the Command that runs every minute, but i want the data to be validated, otherwise my system is hackable via email :P

Comment: Your requirement doesn't really make sense, but did you try just `new ContactRequest()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The data is already in the request. You are able to validate that with Request. You can manually add custom data within the StoreContactRequest rules() method if that's necessary or even you can create custom validation rules: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Thx, but unfortunatelly not. The validate() function is executed right when i create the Request. I dont have the chance to add any data, because it throws the validation error In that line:
$storeContactReq = app()->make(\App\Http\Requests\StoreContactRequest::class); 

i tried to add data here with app()->makeWith(...), but it didnt work either.  

when i dd($this.request) in the rules() of StoreContactRequest, i get an emtpy #parameters: []. Of course, cuz i have no chance to pass any data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding local validators in the store() methods

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'street' => 'required',
            'house' => 'required',
            'postcode' => 'required',
            'city' => 'required',
        ]);
        $validated = $validator->validate();

        //$request->validate($request->all());
        $con = Contact::create($validated);
```

Thats not very convienient, and i guess ill get problems with auth here, but for now it works. Thx all

Comment: Don't resolve `StoreContactRequest`, it will not help. Shoe what's in your request by dd-ing it. If a contact information is in there you can validate it in your `StoreProjectRequest`

Comment: I want to validate it in the StoreContactRequest, because there are other places in my app where i have to add Contacts and Users, independently from this Command function /Project creation. If i create the Request manually with 'new' then i can add() the data, but the Request has validator=null. If i create it with app()->make(), it has a validator, but is resolved immediately, before i can add any data.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose that in the StoreContactRequest class you implement the prepareForValidation() method, and you can add extra validation attributes for it. See this in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#preparing-input-for-validation. Also feel free to redefine the failedValidation method. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php